# Unable to access FTP using Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, ftp

I've set up an FTP site on an AWS EC2 Windows Server 2022 using IIS. I can successfully connect using FileZilla, and can read and write using that connection.

However, when attempting to access it using Windows Explorer on a Windows 11 machine, I get a weird error message with no details, making it hard to diagnose what might be going on.

Screenshot of the detail-less error message:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Disabling the client's firewall
- Opened the ports 20-22, 5000-5099 (for passive FTP) on both Windows Firewall as well as AWS Security Group.
- Set the folder permission for "Everyone" with full access
- Cleared `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\FTP\Accounts`
- Cleared Windows Credentials

What else can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: Check against [this article](https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/201637914-FTP-Access-through-Windows-Explorer).

Comment: I did try the steps there (it was already set as Passive on Internet Options), but it didn't work. We (un)fortunately moved on to another file-sharing solution instead. Thanks for the assistance, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem no longer exists and the user can no longer test answers.